# Is a relative link with parameters and no path allowed?

Tags: html

Am I allowed to omit the path entirely from a href and start with a question mark?

For example: If my webpage is `https://example.com/mycgi`, can I have a link of the form `<a href="?foo=bar">bar</a>`?

I've tested this on Firefox and the link works as expected - clicking it takes me to `https://example.com/mycgi?foo=bar`. Will this work the same way on all modern browsers? What is best practice for this type of link?

I've tried searching MDN which usually has a good table of feature and browser version support, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href doesn't have give details about relative link formats.

I usually use `href="mycgi?foo=bar"`, but it means adding a less portable reference to `mycgi` in the page. I'd prefer not to have to dynamically add `mycgi` to every reference in the cgi which generates the page.

This is a pure html and browser compatibility question. I am not looking for server or client side tools to modify links.

Comment: You should learn about absolute and relative paths. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: @epascarello All the relative URLs there specify at least part of the path. My question is about omitting the path entirely and only specifying parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any issue with it.

You should be able to write any of those and they should resolve like any other link element. You might wan't to test it out on every major browser. But if you find a browser that doesn't support it i'm pretty sure the browser is not up to spec.

```
href="?foo=bar"
```

should resolve to `domain.com/currentPath/CurrentPage?foo=bar`

```
href="newPage?foo=bar"
```

should resolve to `domain.com/currentPath/newPage?foo=bar`

```
href=".?foo=bar"
```

should resolve to `domain.com/currentPath/?foo=bar`

```
href="/?foo=bar"
```

should resolve to `domain.com/?foo=bar`

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the list of alternativs. Do you have a reference for these? I don't have access to "every major browser" - which is one of the reasons I asked this question.

Comment: section specificaly on searchParams : https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams

Comment: posted wrong url before :

few examples 
https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls

I'm pretty sure that if your URL get's parsed, it just works !
So if it works on firefox it should work everywhere.

And if https://google.com/fakefolder/../alsoafakefolder/../search?q=test works, I think you're fine !